# SQL Join table getting average value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

```
+--------+    +----------------+    +------------+ 
| Rating |    | Rating_Person  |    | Person     |
+--------+    +----------------+    +------------+ 
| ID     |    | RAT_ID         |    | ID         |
| RATING |    | PER_ID         |    | AVE_RATING | 
+--------+    +----------------+    | NO_RATINGS |
                                    +------------+
```

An `Person` can have many `Ratings`.

I have a SQL query where I get a List of `Persons`:

```
SELECT * FROM PERSON
```

**Question:**

How do I join the `Rating` table to populate the `AVE_RATING` and `NO_RATINGS` values?

I can do the following to `JOIN` the tables, but how do I calculate the `AVE_RATING` and `NO_RATINGS`?

```
SELECT * FROM PERSON P 
INNER JOIN RATING_PERSON RP ON P.ID = RP.PER_ID
INNER JOIN RATING R ON RP.RAT_ID = R.ID
GROUP BY P.ID
```

Thanks you for any help.

(I am using MySQL)

Comment: Can you please show some expected output

Comment: Thanks TheGameiswar, but I worked out the solution. See below.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
SELECT 
count(R.ID) as NO_ROWS, avg(R.RATING) as AVE_RATING,
P.* FROM PERSON P 
INNER JOIN rating_person RP ON P.ID = RP.PER_ID
INNER JOIN RATING R ON RP.RAT_ID = R.ID
group by P.ID
```